# crack MySQL323 hash

Tags: hash

I'm trying to crack a MySQL323 hash and I'm unable to get it done.

I was able to confirm tye hash type:

[image]

I came across https://www.tobtu.com/mysql323.php.
I can run it as `"mysql323 32.exe" [number of threads] [hash] [keyspace-file]` but there is no reference what the keyspace-file should be.

Trying to crack the hash in hashcat fails as well:

[image]

After few hours I'm close to give up. Any help please ?

PS. The hash was extracted from a MySQL dump from a HTB machine.

Comment: Are you sure this challenge is about cracking a hash? Also adam, how fast are you cracking? How many hashes per second?

Comment: lol how do you know my name ?? I don't care if it is about cracking a hash. There's a way to dump a database, and I can see few user accounts with hashed passwords. The challenge is to gain access to the box.

Comment: Does it work on a different computer? According to [this](https://rc.byu.edu/wiki/index.php?page=I+keep+getting+Illegal+Instruction+errors.+What+do+I+do%3F) it seems like hashcat is trying to use an optimization that your CPU does not support.

Comment: hard to say I'm running inside a VM, might give it a go on bare metal.

Comment: @cyzczy You're on a Stack Exchange site for hackers. It is my job to know things I'm not supposed to know. Also, you didn't answer how fast you're cracking. Secondly, it matters very much - a HTB box is designed to teach you something. If the challenge is to pick a lock and you just break the door with an axe, you technically "entered the room", yet you failed to learn anythng from it.

Comment: @MechMK1 Well, I got a shell in a way that was not included in any of the public writeups (log poisoning via SMTP --> php reberse shell execution via LFI). But when you say challenge, where is it outlined what the challenge for a given htb box is ? I can't see it.

Comment: @cyzczy I don't know the specific box, but usually the name indicates what it's about. It very well might be that you need to crack some hashes - that's why I asked you if you are sure that this is what you're meant to do. Secondly, I have asked twice now how fast your cracking speed is.

Comment: You didn't do a very good job of "erasing" your name from the image.  As a general rule of thumb, if you are going to use a privacy-focused browser, don't use your actual name for your username.  Poor OpSec is what gets most people in trouble.

Comment: @ConorMancone What dou you mean "erasing your name from the image? Could you please explain ? Were you able to pull my username from the pictures metadata or what  ?

Comment: No... in your second screenshot, in the top left, where you fuzzed out [username]@kali - [username] is absolutely still readable